# How to continue your Aircrack-ng Bruteforce where you left off?

Tags: wifi, attacks, aircrack-ng

I am performing a WPA/WPA2-PSK Attack using Aircrack-ng. The Wordlist i am using is 100 GB but i have to Shutdown my PC after a certain time so how am i supposed to continue the Attack where i left off?

Comment: Sorry, I think this question is off-topic for this site. You are asking about how to use a specific piece of software. While the software may be related to information security, your question about the software is only indirectly related to information security.

Comment: @browly How can i edit this Question to get an Answer?

Comment: This is just not the right place. You should consult the aircrack-ng documentation for this question.

Comment: Wouldn't this fall under security tools/pentesting? I understand this site is not a "How do I use this tool" site but this question is quite specific no?

Comment: @Off topic votes, the answer isn't in the manpages, it requires some custom tooling (see accepted answer). Agreed that functionality about tools should be left to their respective boards, but in this case there was no way to achieve what OP was trying without knowledge that doesn't belong on SE imo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is that currently, `aircrack-ng` does not support such a feature.

However, you could achieve the same result with `john` (John  The Ripper) in combination with aircrack.

To start a session `foo` that you want to pause and resume later, execute:

`$ john --session=foo --stdout --wordlist=wordlist.dic | aircrack-ng -w - -b 00:11:22:33:44:55 WPAcrack.cap`

To resume this session `foo` at a later time, run:

`$ john --restore=foo | aircrack-ng -w - -b 00:11:22:33:44:55 WPAcrack.cap`

This will allow you to bypass the `aircrack-ng` limitation.

[Source](https://www.shellhacks.com/pause-resume-aircrack-ng/)

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for the off-topic question. I thought it was a good question. I am new to Stack Exchange, i have only used Stackoverflow before :)

Comment: You're welcome! Generally users here like well explained questions about what you're doing, what's happening and what you were expecting to happen. Also, in general, usage of tools isn't really discussed in a "how do i do x with tool y"-way. Usually that kinda stuff can be found in manpages etc. (But it didn't this time, so I kinda understood the question) And formatting, we just loooove formatting. ;-) Welcome to SE!